# How to open Windows Phone sqlite files?

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

I've copied an sqlite file from a folder of a windows phone application (WP 8.1). I've tried to open with [sqlite browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/), but it said the file format was invalid. How can I open these sqlite files?

Update:
It's a third party application. Because of a software bug I've lost my data. I hope I can restore it from this file. (I'm not a Windows Phone developer.)

Comment: Are you sure it was SQLite and not Linq2Sql? What API did you use to create the database, and what is the filename?

Comment: You need to export your data base file from windows phone device.. Have you exported ?
And which mechanism you are use to create your sqlite database... Please post your approach in your question.